# Can the freeing condition to end imprisonment damage a creature so entrapped?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

According to the imprisonment spell

> **Ending the Spell.** During the casting of the spell, in any of its versions, you can specify a condition that will cause the spell to end and release the target. The condition can be as specific or as elaborate as you choose, but the GM must agree that the condition is reasonable and has a likelihood of coming to pass. The conditions can be based on a creature's name, identity, or deity but otherwise must be based on observable actions or qualities and not based on intangibles such as level, class, or hit points.

Could the spell ending condition cause death or damage? For instance, several thousand feet in the air, in a volcano, underwater so far that they can't swim to the surface.

If the players themselves have a hand in fulfilling the imprisonment's condition to cause the target to die/ take severe damage, is that a valid ending method for the spell?

Comment: I made it broader so that it is dealing with only the ending condition, which is the core question

Comment: Based on your previous question, I have to ask: Why are you working so hard to make Imprisonment kill stuff? If you have 9th level spells, there are so many ways to kill stuff that are so much easier and simpler.

Comment: @Miniman to be creative. To find loopholes in spells that maybe are underused.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The condition can be as specific or as elaborate as you choose, but the GM must agree that the condition is reasonable and has a likelihood of coming to pass.

I can't see how this sentence is in any way cryptic or confusing.

If you want to make the condition: "When the prison is immersed in 1,000 feet of molten lava" is a specific (and not hugely elaborate) condition. If the DM feels that this "is reasonable and has a likelihood of coming to pass" then done and done.

It makes no nevermind if the condition occurs because the PCs lugged it to a volcano and dumped it in or if it happened 3 billion years hence because of geological processes.